# Lazy Val - How to reset value?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I may want to use a method that is expensive and returns a result depending on side effects. For example depending on the time of day / week and a Monte Carlo simulation of quantum chronodynamics. Because it's expensive and I may not need it, I'll use Scalas `lazy val`

```
lazy val maybeUnusedValue = getDayOfWeek
```

Now 12 hours pass with my program still running. I want to redo the calculation, because my day may have changed in the meantime.

Is there a simple way to force Scala to return `maybeUnusedValue` back to uninitialized state, therefore forcing a recalculation on its next usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [make a lazy var in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289243/make-a-lazy-var-in-scala)

Comment: You might be interested in the memoize pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640823/what-type-to-use-to-store-an-in-memory-mutable-data-table-in-scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a simple way

Since "laziness" is implemented with a field to track initialization, the simple solution is to wrap the lazy val with a mutable reference. You'll have to deal with mutability of that reference, of course.

```
scala> class V { lazy val v = System.currentTimeMillis }
defined class V

scala> @volatile var x = new V
x: V = V@77468bd9

scala> x.v
res0: Long = 1431212391127

scala> x.v
res1: Long = 1431212391127

scala> x = new V
x: V = V@28f67ac7

scala> x.v
res2: Long = 1431212407970
```

and then something like

```
scala> import concurrent._, duration._, ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import concurrent._
import duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> implicit class ex(val d: Deadline) extends AnyVal { def expiring(f: => Unit) =
     | Future(Await.ready(Promise().future, d.timeLeft)) onComplete (_ => f) }
defined class ex

scala> 10 seconds fromNow expiring { x = new V }

scala> x.v
res4: Long = 1431212407970

scala> x.v
res5: Long = 1431212407970

scala> x.v
res6: Long = 1431213010180
```

Comment: Wrapping the val in a volatile var seems to be the most general solution (its performance may be inferior, but it is usable for all cases, without extra logic).  Please add a few more lines of explanation for future readers so I can accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Nephtys as the other answer suggests, when to recompute and how to handle the mutable ref are orthogonal concerns. Why don't people ask for a "reset button" on lazy vals more often? If the initializer throws, BTW, the val is recomputed.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into two problems:

- `val` is immutable, i.e. cannot be changed after initialization
- even if you used `var` instead, it has no mechanism to expire after some time

My suggestion would be turn `getDayOfWeek` into a function that tracks the current value and state in some other instance:

```
private var dayOfWeek: Option[Day] = None
private var lastEvaluated: Int = 0

def getDayOfWeek = dayOfWeek match {
  case None => expensiveGetDayOfWeek
  case Some(day) =>
    if (DateTime.now.getDayOfYear > lastEvaluated) expensiveGetDayOfWeek
    else day

}

private def expensiveGetDayOfWeek: Day = {
  dayOfWeek = Some(someExpensiveOperation())
  lastEvaluated = DateTime.now.getDayOfYear
  dayOfWeek.get
}
```

My state tracking of when to recompute is a bit hacky, so you'll want to come up with your own, but the basic gist is that you calculate on demand.