# Lazy evaluations with var

Tags: scala

I know about `lazy val` and that code is evaluated only when it is called, but I am not able to understand certain things with lazy and var.

### Questions

- Why is lazy only allowed with val and not var?
- In intellij, the below error is thrown

Scala version I am using : Scala 2.12.0

[image: lazy val error]

It says lazy is allowed only with value definitions. I am a bit confused here, isnt everything a value in scala? and var is just a keyword right and what it has to do with the type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289243/make-a-lazy-var-in-scala

Comment: `var` are generally not recommanded

Comment: @cchantep ya I am aware of that. Was asking in the specific context of lazy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, some terminology:

- The keyword `val` is used to define a "value definition" - a definition that is evaluated *once*.
- The keyword `var` defines a *variable*, which can be changed after it is first assigned a value.
- So when the compiler says "lazy modifier allowed only with value definitions", it means just that - that only `val` and not `var` can follow the `lazy` keyword.

Why does Scala not support `lazy var`? 
I'm guessing that marking a `var` as lazy would not be well defined: what would be evaluated lazily - the first assignment only? Each and every assignment? And would a re-assignment count as a trigger for the previous assignment or not? There might also be some implementation issues (e.g. how do we make sure a variable isn't assigned while a previous value is being calculated?).

Comment: `val` is a value definition and `var` is a variable in the sense it can change. I guess that clears it up for me. Is there any official documentation on this which I can share around.Thanks.